# How to get index of column based on continuous sequence of values

Tags: javascript, counting

I have this sequence of numbers

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29`

Each number represents a component on a page. Every 3 numbers comprises a page. The component indexing restarts on every page. So basically column-based indexing.

You could think of it as

```
0   1   2
3   4   5
6   7   8
9   10  11
12  13  14
15  16  17
18  19  20
21  22  23
24  25  26
27  28  29
```

where each row is a page, and each column is a component.

I need to identify based on only these numbers which page/row and which component/column the number is in. Page and component counts are 0-based.

I have managed to identify the index of the page/row using `Math.floor(number / 3)`.

How can I identify the component?

For example, `20` would be component 2 on page 6, `10` would be component 1 on page 3, `27` would be component 0 on page 9.

Comment: You will probably want to use modulus instead of division.

Comment: For getting the page and/or component index?

Comment: Take the position and use `%` to get the modulus.  I.e., 5th position:  `5 % 3` -> `2`.

Comment: Please provide an example of a desired result based on your example.

Comment: Edited my question with example of desired result @PM77-1

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, Actually OP needs both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use modulus operator :

```
var component = number % 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `%` to get the component, and division to get the page like this:

```js
/*
0   1   2
3   4   5
6   7   8
9   10  11
12  13  14
15  16  17
18  19  20
21  22  23
24  25  26
27  28  29
*/

function componentInfo(offset) {
  return {
    page: Math.floor(offset / 3),
    component: offset % 3
  }
}

console.log(componentInfo(6))
console.log(componentInfo(10))
console.log(componentInfo(22))
```

Comment: Math.floor instead of Math.ceil because I'm using 0-based indexing but other than that this is it